# How can I get the current move from the score director?

Tags: optaplanner

We are using the "auto delay until last" pattern from the docs, https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html

The loop detection computation is extremely expensive, and we would like to minimize the number of times it is called. Right now, it is being called in the `@AfterVariableChanged` method of the arrival time shadow variable listener.

The only information I have available in that method is the stop that got a new previous stop and the score director. A move may change several planning variables, so I will be doing the loop detection once for every planning variable that changed, when I should only have to do it once per move (and possibly undo move, unless I can be really clever and cache the loop detection result across moves).

Is there a way for me, from the score director, to figure out what move is being executed right now? I have no need to know exactly what move or what kind of move is being performed, only whether I am still in the same move as before.

I tried using `scoreDirector.toString()`, which has an incrementing number in it, but that number appears to be the same for a move and the corresponding undo move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no access to a move from scoring code. That is by design - scoring needs to be independent of moves executed. Any solution has a score, and if two solutions represent the same state of the problem, their scores must equal - therefore the only thing that matters for the purposes of scoring is the state of the solution, not the state of the solver or any other external factor.

Comment: That makes 100% sense. However, that forces me into these inefficient calculations. Could I do the loop detection somewere else? If I understand the flow correctly, a move changes a number X of genuine planning variables, then it starts updating all corresponding shadow variables. Is there a way to insert myself in between the genuine variable updates and shadow variable updates?

Step 1: Update X genuine planning variables. Step 2: Run loop detection code ONCE and store result in working solution. Step 3: Run shadow variable listeners, making use of the stored loop detection result

Comment: As far as I know, there is not. I see that there is an inefficiency built into this system, but I think that we currently do not have a solution to that. Maybe other answers will correct me.

Comment: If there is no current way of doing it, I think it would make a nice addition to be able to plug in code in this manner. There could be many scenarios where shadow variable listeners run code per planning variable that would only be needed per move.

Comment: I agree. I filed https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2594, but as always, there are no promises if/when we get to it.

Comment: That's all I can ask for. Hope you get to it eventually!

Comment: Overwriting `VariableListener.requiresUniqueEntityEvents()` to return `true` might give you the behavior you need.